# Error with pip install face_recognition module in python terminal

Tags: python, pip, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to install the face_recognition module in my terminal for a project but I am having trouble with some of the error messages. I already ran pip install on cmake and dlib but whenever I try running pip install face_recognition or pipenv install face_recognition, I get the following error message:

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem
with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

I am not quite sure what this means and I have been looking around to the best of my ability to solve the problem. I have already installed dlib through pip.

Comment: Try on a new env to do pip install cmake and then pip install face_recognition (skip dlib) . For me it worked in python 3.9

Comment: I just set up a new env to try this and I got the same output. It works when I install cmake and face_recognition but when I run pipenv install face_recognition, I get the same result.

Comment: Why do you need pipenv?

Comment: On a previous project, pipenv seemed to resolve the issue of properly importing the face_recognition package but in all honestly I could be wrong in doing this. pip installing cmake and face_recognition didn't seem to properly import the face_recognition package so I'm not quite sure.

Comment: can you send the command that u used and did not work?

Comment: I used "pip install cmake" and "pip install face_recognition". The terminal said they worked but would not install the face_recognition package when I used an import statement. Afterwards, I tried "pipenv install face_recognition", where I ran into the error message I highlighted.